# android Implement chatting through push notification using parse.com api

Tags: java, android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am doing a chat application . In the app i have to do chatting with help of push notifications using parse andorid sdk. I am successfull to generate push notications between different users . But not able to recieve push and add their data in list view . Here is code of maifest file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />





<application
    android:name="example.chat.ChatApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


     <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="example.chat.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="example.chat.FriendslIst"
        android:label="Friend list"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="example.chat.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="example.chat.FriendListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_friend_list"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="example.chat.ChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chat"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>



     <receiver android:name="example.chat.MyCustomReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="example.chat.UPDATE_STATUS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

and code for my custom reciever

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Toast.makeText(context, ""+intent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

and from java code I am sending push like this :

```
ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("device_id", target);
        ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        push.setQuery(query);
        push.setMessage(message);
        push.setExpirationTimeInterval(86400);
        push.sendInBackground();
```

Please tell me where I am wrong for recieving data using reciever and what to do when i recive push means any logic or idea to move further . Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide me some links to make chat app using parse.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the manifiest file.....

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="your package name"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="your package name.YourActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

            <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <receiver android:name="your package name.YourCustomReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                    <action android:name="your package name.UPDATE_STATUS" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

use this code to receive the push...

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

String title, from, msg;

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String message = extras != null ? extras.getString("com.parse.Data")
                : "";

        Log.e("message ", " " + message);

        JSONObject jObject;
        try {
            if (message != null && !message.equals("")) {
                jObject = new JSONObject(message);

                from = jObject.getString("from");
                msg = jObject.getString("title");
                title = jObject.getString("msg");



                GCMMessage gcmMessage = new GCMMessage();
                gcmMessage.setMsg_body(msg);
                gcmMessage.setMsg_title(title);
                gcmMessage.setType(0);
                gcmMessage.setDateTime(time);



                DatabaseUtil.insertMessage(context, gcmMessage);
            }

        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

and here is the code to send push...

```
    JSONObject obj;
            try {
                obj =new JSONObject();
                obj.put("alert","oman expert ");
                obj.put("action","Your Package name.UPDATE_STATUS");



data.put("from", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());         


    obj.put("msg","hi");
    obj.put("title","msg");
                ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
                ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();



                push.setQuery(query);
                push.setData(obj);
                push.sendInBackground(); 
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

for any further query please let me know....

Answer (score 0):

In the above code example, you have missed out few things,

Check your AndroidManifest.xml file, and add c2dm permissions,

> permission android:name="your package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"                android:protectionLevel="signature"
>
> uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"
>
> uses-permission android:name="your package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"

While sending the data, set the action in your data,

```
 JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    try {
        data.put("action", "your package.GOT_MESSAGE");
        data.put("ya", ya);
        data.put("from", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }


    ParsePush parsePush = new ParsePush();
    parsePush.setData(data);
```