# push notification with parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

i've got a problem showing notification on my android device, i utilize parse.com website, is there a better way to send notification? and how can i solve this?

This is my Androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bpartyorg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bpartyorg.ShowPopUp"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.bpartyorg.MyCustomReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.example.bpartyorg.UPDATE_STATUS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This i my MyReceiver

```
package com.example.bpartyorg;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            if (intent == null)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Receiver intent null");
            }
            else
            {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action );
                if (action.equals("com.example.bpartyorg.UPDATE_STATUS"))
                {
                    String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

                    Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
                    Iterator itr = json.keys();
                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                        String key = (String) itr.next();
                        if (key.equals("customdata"))
                        {
                            Intent pupInt = new Intent(context, ShowPopUp.class);
                            pupInt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
                            context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(pupInt);
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

i use PARSE.COM in "pushes sent" i have "1", so it sends push notification, but my android device doesn't show it how can i solve this problem?

Comment: In Parse, under "Push notifications", make sure your client in enabled.

Comment: My only other suggestion is to run through the troubleshooting guide for parse, which can be found here.  https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#troubleshooting/Android

Comment: please see this link  i have answerd http://stackoverflow.com/a/24949806/3310181