# Receive data from a json by push notification

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com to display a notification in push format , you would have to click on this notification when it opens another Acitivity and pulls up data for a JSON sent as notification with the push

mycode:

```
    Parse.initialize(this, "MY_KEY1", "MY_KEY2");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

I wish through this json using parse.com sends me up to one activity called InformacoesActivity with the data from this json

```
{"alert": "Av. Governador Danilo de Matos Areosa, 381 - Distrito Industrial Manaus - AM", 
"title": "Fucapi",
"name": "My name here"}
```

I would pick the name attribute and display on the screen

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24949806/3310181