# When i register an Android app in Parse GCMSenderIr and deviceToken are undefined

Tags: android, parse-platform, permissions, google-cloud-messaging

Well, i register an app in Parse, when i test my app, the app send my installation information but the GCMSenderIr and deviceToken are undefined. this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.nativescript.SampleNotify"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="org.nativescript.SampleNotify.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="org.nativescript.SampleNotify.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="org.nativescript.SampleNotify" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my code

```
public void onCreate() {
  Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");
  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
```

I no get any error, but i not get these information

[Row in Parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjnYG.png)

here a capture, thank you

Comment: why do you need GCMsenderId ? have a look here to send the push notification using parse : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24949806/3310181

Answer (score 0):

OK. so, you can check the next:

1. Ensure your class "com.tns.NativeScriptApplication" are extending from Application (why both packages are different? org.nativescript.SampleNotify != com.tns)
2. Check my configuration: https://github.com/tiveor/android-advanced/blob/master/ParsePushTest/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
3. Review your onCreate code that is implementing super.onCreate https://github.com/tiveor/android-advanced/blob/master/ParsePushTest/app/src/main/java/com/possiblelabs/parsepushtest/MyApplication.java
4. Check your AppId and Client Key (could have some extra space).

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't, you need to add dependency to Google Cloud Messaging Play Services library in order to let Parse get the GCM registration token.

Check dependencies in your build.gradle and add if necessary:

compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"